# MySQL Query get the last record then join

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table like this:

**table account**

```
id | username 
 1 | myuser123
 2 | secretuser
```

**table subscription**

```
id | username    | subsStartDate | subsEndDate
 1 | myuser123   |  2017-01-19   | 2017-02-19
 2 | secretuser|  2017-01-19   | 2017-02-19
 3 | myuser123   |  2017-02-19   | 2017-03-19
 4 | secretuser|  2017-02-19   | 2017-03-19
```

How can I get the **latest** `subsEndDate` of each **user** in table `account`.
I am looking for an output similar to this:

**output looking for**

```
id | username    | subsStartDate | subsEndDate
 3 | myuser123   |  2017-02-19   | 2017-03-19
 4 | secretuser|  2017-02-19   | 2017-03-19
```

Comment: `SELECT UserName,MAX(subsStartDate ),MAX(subsEndDate) from table group by username`??

Comment: @JaydipJadhav Where's id in all of that?

Comment: Replace everywhere "secreatuser" to "secretuser". I think it's a mistake.

Comment: @Strawberry Hmm! I missed it that column. good catch ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this :

```
SELECT s.id, s.username, s.subsStartDate, endate as subsEndDate
FROM 
  subscription s
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT id, Max(subsEndDate) as endate
    FROM subscription
    GROUP BY id) t ON t.id = s.id
```

Comment: as I tried without subquery, just  `group by` with `username` is output the same results.

Comment: Yes but it's because MySQL is the only SQL language who permits it to not group by all the non aggregate function, it's not a good habit to do it.

Comment: With the inner join, i "eliminate" the id who are not the max.

Comment: No. You're just confusing yourself, and the OP.

Comment: In what ? You are not making any sense !!

Comment: This query gets the highest subsEndDate for each id. As id is unique that is bringing back every subsEndDate from the sub query, then joining on the id.  To work the sub query group by and the join would need to to be on the username. Even then there is the technical possibility that 2 records for a username could share the same subsEndDate but have different subsStartDate so the username would be returned twice.

Answer (score 1):

To get the row with latest `subsEndDate` per user you can use following query

```
select a.*
from subscription a
left join subscription b on a.username = b.username
and a.subsEndDate < b.subsEndDate 
where b.id is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa9c8/1)

Comment: You can, but I think it's best to consign this query to the Hall of History.

Answer (score 1):

A variant for the case where order `id` isn't equals order `max_subsEndDate`

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscription s
JOIN
  (
    SELECT username,MAX(subsEndDate) max_subsEndDate
    FROM subscription
    GROUP BY username
  ) l
ON s.username=l.username AND s.subsEndDate=l.max_subsEndDate
```

My variant (if order `id` is equals order `max_subsEndDate`)

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
WHERE id IN(
      SELECT MAX(id)
      FROM subscription
      GROUP BY username
    )
```

A variant with `JOIN`

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscription s
JOIN
  (
    SELECT MAX(id) max_id
    FROM subscription
    GROUP BY username
  ) l
ON s.id=l.max_id
```

Comment: I have always heard that a IN in mysql has to be avoid because it cost a lot more than an Inner Join.

Comment: @Jean Doux - I think the optimizer can replace `IN` into `JOIN`. At least the SQLServer optimizer often do it. I think that the MySQL optimizer also do it. Need to check. I edited my ansver. SQLServer often returns the similar exicution plans for these two queries.

Comment: @Jean Doux - Yes, MySQL also can replace `IN` into `JOIN`. I think It depends from some factors. For example, queries for `A2` and `B2` return the similar exicution plans (because table `B2` containts `PRIMARY KEY` on `ID`) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f8b3a/1

Comment: The OP is interested in the value with the max date. It's merely coincidence that the value with the max date is also the value with the max id.

Comment: @Strawberry - You're right. I added a variant for this case. Thank you!

Comment: Great - although I would note that it looks remarkably similar to an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM subscription a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT username
            , MAX(subsenddate) subsenddate 
         FROM subscription 
        GROUP 
           BY username
     ) b 
    ON b.username = a.username 
   AND b.subsenddate = a.subsenddate;
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see why your query is better, it's seems same.

Comment: @JeanDoux This topic is very widely discussed; it even has its own chapter in the manual, so I'm discinclined to elaborate - but I can if you insist. That said, at present, your query simply returns all rows.